# How to add margins to a <br> tags?

Tags: php, css

I am in a bit of a predicament.  I have the nl2br function which will add spaces/breaks to sentences, but the gap is too big and the output looks to spaced out.  So I realized I can use `#br` and give a `margin-top` etc, but that will mess up other `<br>` where there is only one line by default.

Is there a way that I can either replace the `<br>` with a `<br id>` tag or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you add a css class or id to the parent tag and then us CSS to style the child containers / tag?

Comment: so for example:  if its in a div called "test".  #test.br ?

Comment: #test br{/* add css rules in here */}